# How to fix TypeError: cannot concatenate object of type '<class 'pandas.io.parsers.TextFileReader'>'; only Series and DataFrame objs are valid?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, concatenation, export-to-csv

I am trying to read csv files and concatenate them and output them as one csv file. I keep getting this error:

> TypeError: cannot concatenate object of type '< class 'pandas.io.parsers.TextFileReader'>'; only Series and DataFrame objs are valid;

I am not sure how to fix it. I am a beginner, so I would appreciate any help! Thank you! Here is the code I wrote:

```
csv.field_size_limit(sys.maxsize)
df1 = pd.read_csv('file1.csv', chunksize=20000)
df2 = pd.read_csv('file2.csv', chunksize=20000)
df3 = pd.read_csv('file3.csv', chunksize=20000)
df4 = pd.read_csv('file4.csv', chunksize=20000)
df5 = pd.read_csv('file5.csv', chunksize=20000)
df6 = pd.read_csv('file6.csv', chunksize=20000)

frames = [df1, df2, df3, df4, df5, df6]
result = pd.concat(frames, ignore_index=True, sort=False)
result.to_csv('new.csv')
```

Comment: does all this `df` have same number of columns?

Comment: are you sure all the files have 20000 rows ?

Answer (score 2):

If you call *read_csv* passing *chunksize* parameter, then:

- it returns a *TextFileReader* object,
- which can be used, e.g. in a loop, to read and process
  consecutive chunks.

An example of how to use "chunked" CSV file reading:

```
reader = pd.read_csv('input.csv', chunksize=20000)
for chunk in reader:
    # Process the chunk (DataFrame)
```

Or maybe you want to:

- read **only initial 20000 rows** from each source file,
- concatenate them into a new DataFrame?

If this is the case, pass *nrows=20000* (instead of *chunksize*),
while reading from each file.
Then all returned objects will be just DataFrames and you will be able
to *concat* them.